# Convert 4 columns to just 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose that I have the following table:

```
------------------------------------
Name1 | Address1 | Name2 | Address2
------------------------------------
AAA   | Tokyo    | CCCC  | Brazil
EEE   | paris    | FFFF  | Cairo
```

I need a query in sql server to give me two (2) columns only

```
----------------
Name  | Address 
----------------
AAA   | Tokyo  
CCCC  | Brazil
EEE   | paris 
FFFF  | Cairo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNION ALL:

```
insert into final_table
  select Name1 name, Address1 address from init_table
  union all
  select Name2 name, Address2 address from init_table;
```

Comment: Note that the query being asked for doesn't include the first line -- according to my interpretation.